# Regex: Solution for arbitrary alpha numeric lengths

Tags: php, regex

My requirement is to have a number allowed between `E000001T` to `E999999T` where `E` and `T` are constant however number between these letters should be from `000001 to 999999`.

I tried this regex:

`E\d{6}T`

However I am not sure how to enforce min and max range `000001 to 999999`.

Comment: just use flag `i` for ignore_case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To enforce range use a negative lookahead to disallow all zeroes between `E` and `T`
2. For ignore case matching use `/i` flag

Regex would be:

```
/E(?!0+T)\d{6}T/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sy7IZB/2)

`(?!0+T)` is negative lookahead to assert failure when we have all zeroes between `E` and `T`